# Rails changing table name in has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite

I have two models `StageBatch` and `StageItem`:

```
class StageItem < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :stage_batches
end

class StageBatch < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :stage_items
end
```

With the following migration:

```
class CreateStageBatchesAndStageItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :stage_items do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :stage_batches do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :stage_batches_and_stage_items, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :stage_item, index: true
      t.belongs_to :stage_batch, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

When I try to access a `stage_batches` `stage_items` I get the following error:

```
irb(main):002:0> StageBatch.first.stage_items
  StageBatch Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "stage_batches".* FROM "stage_batches" ORDER BY "stage_batches"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  StageItem Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "stage_items".* FROM "stage_items" INNER JOIN "stage_batches_items" ON "stage_items"."id" = "stage_batches_items"."stage_item_id" WHERE "stage_batches_items"."stage_batch_id" = ?  [["stage_batch_id", 1]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: stage_batches_items: SELECT "stage_items".* FROM "stage_items" INNER JOIN "stage_batches_items" ON "stage_items"."id" = "stage_batches_items"."stage_item_id" WHERE "stage_batches_items"."stage_batch_id" = ?
```

- Is there something wrong with my migration?
- Is there something wrong with the naming conventions?
- Why does it seem like my table got its name changed from `stage_batches_and_stage_items` to `
  Is there something wrong with my migration?
- Is there something wrong with the naming conventions? Why does it seem like my table got its name changed from `stage_batches_and_stage_items` to `stage_batches_items`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to follow the Rails naming convention for naming the joining table while using `has_and_belongs_to_many`. Alternatively, you can specify a joining table name using `join_table` option.

In your particular case, change the `stage_batches_and_stage_items`'s name to `stage_batches_stage_items`. By default, the joining table has both table names (pluralized) in lexical order.

From the [Rails guide [Section 3.3.2]](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#updating-the-schema):

> If you create a has_and_belongs_to_many association, you need to
>   explicitly create the joining table. Unless the name of the join table
>   is explicitly specified by using the :join_table option, Active Record
>   creates the name by using the lexical book of the class names. So a
>   join between author and book models will give the default join table
>   name of "authors_books" because "a" outranks "b" in lexical ordering.

I would recommend avoiding `has_and_belongs_to_many` if this is not a hard requirement due to it's limitations (e.g., you can't add any extra columns to this joining table.) Instead, use [has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association. In that case, you can customize the joined table name easily. Also, you can add extra columns to the joining table as you need.

Here is how the code will look like using `has_many :through` association:

```
class StageItem < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stage_item_batches
  has_many :stage_batches, through: :stage_item_batches
end

# joining model
class StageItemBatch < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :stage_item
  belongs_to :stage_batch
end

class StageBatch < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stage_item_batches
  has_many :stage_items, through: :stage_item_batches
end
```

The migrations for original two models will stay the same. You just need a migration for the joining model:

```
rails g model StageItemBatch stage_item:references stage_batch:references
```

Comment: +1 for a clear explanation, helpful link, and useful advice about moving forward. Would also appreciate an example implementation using `has_many :through`

Comment: Will update my answer shortly with `has_many :through` example.

Comment: Can you also include the relevant migration?

Comment: sure. The migrations for original two models will stay the same. You just need a migration for the joining model: `rails g model StageItemBatch stage_item:references stage_batch:references`

Comment: is the convention to name it `StageItemBatch` instead of `StageItemStageBatch`?

Comment: It's not a convention. you can name it anything basically :) The table name and hence the `through` option will change accordingly.

Comment: The migration generated using your command looks different than the one recomended in the [The has_many :through Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) section of the docs. Does `t.belongs_to :stage_item, index: true` mean the same thing as `t.references :stage_item, foreign_key: true`?

Comment: yeah, they are basically same thing. You can add `index: true` option if you need as well.